# List of banks with free OFX service

Tags: banking, gnucash, services, ofx

I am looking for a list of banks that offer a free OFX (Open Financial Exchange) service. The best list I have been able to find is here:

[OFX List](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/OFX_Direct_Connect_Bank_Settings)

Some of the banks on this list are documented to explicitly charge a price for OFX service. For others it doesn't say and I would assume there is no charge. As I cannot verify banks without creating a lot of accounts, I seek the advice here of the stackexchange community.

I am planning on using gnucash, and the idea is to get a closer to real time estimate of my financial state. All help is welcome!

Comment: I think this question is definitely ON-TOPIC, not off-topic, because as a matter of fact the original poster is NOT asking for "product or service recommendations". He is asking for specific ways how get information on OFX services offered in general. This has nothing to do with asking for recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, *most* of the banks out there charge a fee for automated downloads of banking data.  The only exceptions that I'm aware of are for high-value accounts, i.e. worth $100K+.  Even though the list you provided is titled "OFX" (Open format), most of them are implemented as "QFX" (Quicken proprietary).  In order for a bank to implement Quicken exchange connections, they must pay a licensing fee to Intuit, which the banks then pass along to their customers who utilize the service (list banks with Quicken support [here](https://www.quicken.com/support/list-banks-offer-direct-connect-bill-pay-quicken-mac-2016)).

If you are using the Linux version of GnuCash, you can work around this by using the scripting interface (python) to automate downloading data, but that takes some programming knowledge to implement (see [here](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Python_Bindings) for more details).

EDIT: See [here](https://qlc.intuit.com/questions/918058-what-banks-don-t-charge-to-download-to-quicken) for a similar question on the Intuit site, the list of free banks is small..